# Why does "sort -d" fail for words with accents?

Tags: shell, sorting, diacritics

How to get correct sort ignoring case for these word:

```
Diplôme
éboueur
Français
```

On MAcOs Monterey, Macbook Pro, `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0)`, `sort (GNU coreutils) 9.0`,

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Can anyone explain these results:

```
$ echo $'Français\nDiplôme\néboueur' | sort
Diplôme
Français
éboueur

$ echo $'Français\nDiplôme\néboueur' | sort -f
Diplôme
Français
éboueur

$ echo $'Français\nDiplôme\néboueur' | sort -fn
Diplôme
Français
éboueur

# try without accent to compare
$ echo $'Français\nDiplôme\neboueur' | sort -f
Diplôme
eboueur
Français

$ echo $'Français\nDiplôme\néboueur' | sort -d
sort: string comparison failed: Illegal byte sequence
sort: Set LC_ALL='C' to work around the problem.
sort: The strings compared were ‘Dipl\303me’ and ‘\303boueur’.

$ LC_ALL=C echo $'Français\nDiplôme\néboueur' | sort -d
sort: string comparison failed: Illegal byte sequence
sort: Set LC_ALL='C' to work around the problem.
sort: The strings compared were ‘Dipl\303me’ and ‘\303boueur’.
```

Comment: Your previous question mentioned MacOS Monterey. I'm not on Monterey yet so not exactly the same env, but I can't repro (locale `C`, `LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"`, using Bash, like apparently you are too; trying with `LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8` changes nothing)

Comment: `Dipl\303me` is definitely not UTF-8. It's looking like something is eating the second byte out of the UTF-8 sequence. How exactly have you configured Bash's input settings? Which version of Bash? Which version of `sort`? (I have Bash 3.2 and `sort` version "2.3-Apple (106)".)

Comment: Does `echo $'Fran\xc3\xa7ais\nDipl\xc3\xb4me\n\xc3\xa9boueur' | sort -d` work correctly?

Comment: Is `LANG` the only locale variable you set? Perhaps still [edit] to provide the output of `locale`

Comment: added output of Locale to question,

Comment: I believe it is due to macos using an old libc-implementation. I tried on FreeBSD 13 and this sorts correct. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/255228/different-sort-despite-same-collation-in-postgres

Comment: So in my case I resorted to postgresql on docker to get correct sorting in macos.